# download iCloud backup to a Windows computer

Tags: ios, backup, icloud, libimobiledevice

iCloud Backup.
Is there a command within libidimobile that connect to iCloud and allow one to download a backup to a computer providing that one can authenticate properly?

What is expected is to be able to download iCloud backup to a computer after authenticate with the service (that is, have the ID, the password, and subsequently the code asked by the service)